# Fibonacci Range in Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

Hey guys i would like to create a java programm to find fibonacci sequence within a range of numbers. Now i would like to put another input so that i can get the inputs value of the fibonacci nubers

For example if the min is 10 and max is 150 the result will be 13       21      35        55       89      144 but in the third input i would like if the value is 2 to give me only 13 and 21 as result.

Any help??

My Code is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String x = t1.getText();
                String y = t3.getText();
                String o = t4.getText();
                if (x.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestFibMethodRange.this, "This field cannot be empty", "Required Field", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (y.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestFibMethodRange.this, "This field cannot be empty", "Required Field", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (o.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestFibMethodRange.this, "This field cannot be empty", "Required Field", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    if (isInteger(x) && isInteger(y) && isInteger(o)) {
                        int min = Integer.valueOf(x);
                        int max = Integer.valueOf(y);
                        int nSequence = Integer.valueOf(o);
                        for (int i = min; i <= nSequence; i++) {
                            if (x3 <= max) {
                                if (x3 >= min) {
                                    t2.setText(t2.getText() + " " + x3);
                                }
                                x1 = x2;
                                x2 = x3;
                                x3 = x1 + x2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Use [*Binet's formula*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html), hope that helps.

Comment: I have no idea of how to use this. can u help??

Comment: *Now i would like to put another input so that i can get the inputs value of the fibonacci nubers*. I don't understand this sentence...

Comment: @CommuSoft : he meant `javac - MyClass 10 150 2` means he want to print first 2 fibonaaci numbers between 10 & 150.

Comment: @FahimParkar: thanks, found it out some minute later (see answer below).

Comment: why don't put all fibonacci numbers in one array and print how many numbers you want to display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program probably doesn't work properly, because `o` is the number of expected items, but you first need to calculate the "offset" and thus already count some numbers that are too low. In other words `i` has already a value larger than `0` when emitting actually begins.

A better approach:

```
int xa = 0, xb = 0, xc = 1;
while(xc < min) {
    xa = xb;
    xb = xc;
    xc += xa;
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < nSequence && xc <= max; i++) {
    sb.append(xc);
    sb.append(' ');
    xa = xb;
    xb = xc;
    xc += xa;
}
t2.setText(sb.toString());
```

[**Demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/fd).

Comment: @FahimParkar: it requires one to send data to [recruitcoders.com](http://recruitcoders.com). In other words a third party request/privacy breach.

Comment: @FahimParkar: Well i didn't set a text field, but wrote to `stdout` since there is no graphical shell.